Coding firmware for an analog mouse
Hey guys I'm pretty new to firmwares and coding IDE's but I'm building an analog mouse for a project and I'd like to get started on making it functional.
I know how to code the buttons, microswitches and the analog, along with the circuits for the Mboard. I'm just a bit confused on how to compile it and attach it to windows via usb.
Do i need a device controller on board?
What would be the best device controller to do so?
And
Is there a forum, video, website or books I can properly educate myself better?
I have no problem sharing my code and taking advice, I love to learn and hope someone may have the time to explain how it works.
I am pretty familiar with coding so it would not be like explaining it to a brick :D
